# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'AR' not found

Tags: r, debugging, simulation

Sorry about this stupid question guys... but seems that I really need some help with this part of the new project:

```
k1 = 1e-6
k2 = 2e-7
k3 = 1e-10
k4 = 1e-12
k5 = 1e-12
k6 = 3e-14
k7 = 4e-12
k8 = 5e-15
k9 = 6e-12
k10 = 7e-13
k11 = 1e-11
k12 = 1e-12
data2 <- read.csv
t = data2$XA*10000
B = 1E-6
A = B*t^(3/2)
R0 = 1e-5
e = exp(1)
AR1 = (k1*R0*e^-((k1+k2)*t)+k2*R0)/(k1+k2)
ARI = (k3*AR*e^-((k3+k4)*t+k4*AR))/(k3+k4)
RI = (k5*ARI*e^-((k5+k6)*t+k6*ARI))/(k5+k6)
R = (k7*RI*e^-((k7+k8)*t+k8*RI))/(k7+k8)
AR2 = (k9*R*e^-((k9+k10)*t+k10*R))/(k9+k10)
AR = AR1 + AR2
Effect = (k11*AR*e^-((k11+k12)*t+k12*ARI))/(k11+k12)
plot(t, Effect)
```

Then it turns out this result:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'AR' not found
```

Actually it's a part of multi-phase chemical reaction chain simulation. Is that the problem of the lacking of the if...else statement? Sorry I'm totally new in R right now. Thanks.

Here is the data set FYI

```
XA
0
1.00E-10
5.00E-09
9.90E-09
1.48E-08
1.97E-08
2.46E-08
2.95E-08
3.44E-08
3.93E-08
9.00E-04
1.00E-03
2.00E-03
3.00E-03
4.00E-03
5.00E-03
6.00E-03
7.00E-03
8.00E-03
9.00E-03
1.00E-02
```

Comment: data imported with no problem and omitted for convenient; the AR definition doesn't work either if change its order.

Comment: I saw your edit and appended your actual data to my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no possible ordering of rows that isn't circular logic.

`R` is in the definition of `AR2` but the definition of `R` depends on `RI` which depends on `ARI` and thus `AR` and thus `AR2`. So it's circular.

Let's assume that one of these is a mistake. Since there's not enough information for me to know which is the mistake I will assume `RI` should not be in the definition of `R`.

By fixing the circular logic we now have working code:

```
k1 = 1e-6
k2 = 2e-7
k3 = 1e-10
k4 = 1e-12
k5 = 1e-12
k6 = 3e-14
k7 = 4e-12
k8 = 5e-15
k9 = 6e-12
k10 = 7e-13
k11 = 1e-11
k12 = 1e-12
data("mtcars")
data2 <- mtcars
t      = data2$mpg*10000
B      = 1E-6
A      = B*t^(3/2)
R0     = 1e-5
e      = exp(1)
R      = (k7*e^-((k7+k8)*t+k8))/(k7+k8) #*RI
AR1    = (k1*R0*e^-((k1+k2)*t)+k2*R0)/(k1+k2)
AR2    = (k9*R*e^-((k9+k10)*t+k10*R))/(k9+k10)
AR     = AR1 + AR2
ARI    = (k3*AR*e^-((k3+k4)*t+k4*AR))/(k3+k4)
RI     = (k5*ARI*e^-((k5+k6)*t+k6*ARI))/(k5+k6)
Effect = (k11*AR*e^-((k11+k12)*t+k12*ARI))/(k11+k12)
plot(t, Effect)
```

[image]

**Update**

I saw your edit where you added `data2` -- thanks. Here's the solution using your actual data:

```
XA
0
1.00E-10
5.00E-09
9.90E-09
1.48E-08
1.97E-08
2.46E-08
2.95E-08
3.44E-08
3.93E-08
9.00E-04
1.00E-03
2.00E-03
3.00E-03
4.00E-03
5.00E-03
6.00E-03
7.00E-03
8.00E-03
9.00E-03
1.00E-02

data2 <- read.table(con<-file("clipboard"),header=T)


k1 = 1e-6
k2 = 2e-7
k3 = 1e-10
k4 = 1e-12
k5 = 1e-12
k6 = 3e-14
k7 = 4e-12
k8 = 5e-15
k9 = 6e-12
k10 = 7e-13
k11 = 1e-11
k12 = 1e-12
t      = data2$XA*10000
B      = 1E-6
A      = B*t^(3/2)
R0     = 1e-5
e      = exp(1)
R      = (k7*e^-((k7+k8)*t+k8))/(k7+k8) #*RI
AR1    = (k1*R0*e^-((k1+k2)*t)+k2*R0)/(k1+k2)
AR2    = (k9*R*e^-((k9+k10)*t+k10*R))/(k9+k10)
AR     = AR1 + AR2
ARI    = (k3*AR*e^-((k3+k4)*t+k4*AR))/(k3+k4)
RI     = (k5*ARI*e^-((k5+k6)*t+k6*ARI))/(k5+k6)
Effect = (k11*AR*e^-((k11+k12)*t+k12*ARI))/(k11+k12)
plot(t, Effect)
```

[image]